# Can one partition the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ by closed intervals of equal length?

Tags: general-topology, real-numbers

I found in [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/q/48565) the following question:

> Can one partition the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$ by closed intervals of equal length?

Then it is written: "The answer to the first question is "yes"". **My question is: why is the answer 'yes'?**

I think that the length should be $>0$, otherwise it is obviously true and uninteresting. According to [Partitioning $[0,1]$ into pairwise disjoint nondegenerate closed intervals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396329/partitioning-0-1-into-pairwise-disjoint-nondegenerate-closed-intervals), [Can $\mathbb R$ be written as the disjoint union of (uncountably many) closed intervals?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/978823/can-mathbb-r-be-written-as-the-disjoint-union-of-uncountably-many-closed-in), [Is $[0,1]$ a countable disjoint union of closed sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6314/is-0-1-a-countable-disjoint-union-of-closed-sets?noredirect=1&lq=1), this can't be done in dimension $1$.

Thank you!

Comment: According to [this abstract](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.503.5533), such a partition of the plane *does* exist.

Comment: @People who find my post unclear: I would like to know how to partition the plane by closed intervals of equal length.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7593/decomposing-the-plane-into-intervals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A construction of such partition into unit closed closed segments is in:

J. Conway, H. Croft, Covering a sphere with congruent great-circle arcs.
Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 60 (1964) p. 787–800.

Moreover, they use only countably many different slopes in the construction.

A sketch of their construction you can also find in chapter 12 of

M.Gardner, Knotted Doughnuts and Other Mathematical Entertainments, W.H. Freeman & Company, 1986.

Edit. They also prove that the plane cannot be partitioned into **open** unit intervals. Lastly, it is easy to see that the plane can be partitioned into vertical/horizontal open intervals of lengths $1$ and $2$.