# Closed set written as an union of images of curves implies that at least one of those images is closed?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^2$ be a closed set. Suppose $A=\bigcup_{i\in\Lambda}U_i$ as a disjoint union, where $U_i$ is the image of some $C^1$ injective curve $\gamma_i:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^2$. There is $j\in\Lambda$ such that $U_j$ is closed?

Comment: I suspect you forgot the adjective "injective" for $\gamma_i$'s.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1907925/can-one-partition-the-plane-mathbbr2-by-closed-intervals-of-equal-length/1909655#1909655

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am told to add at least 30 characters but isn't a picture  worth a thousand words?

[image]

---

**EDIT**.  Two curves are enough!

[image]

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks!