# Is there a partition of an open square into closed segments (not reduced to a point)?

Tags: general-topology, integer-partitions

Let $C$ be an open square (for example $]0, 1[ \times ]0, 1[$)of the plane $\mathbf R^2$.
Is there a partition of $C$ into closed segments (not reduced to a point) ?

Comment: I asked about covering the plane with closed segments [here on math](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7593/decomposing-the-plane-into-intervals) and then [here on mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43611/decomposing-the-plane-into-intervals)  The plane can be covered by closed intervals.  Unfortunately I lost the cited paper Conway and Croft Covering a sphere with congruent great-circle arcs. Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 60 1964 787–800 so I don't know if the construction extends to the open square.

Comment: Are the segments closed within C or within  RxR?

Comment: @WilliamElliot:  It has to be closed within $\Bbb {R \times R}$.  Closed within $C$ allows just taking all the horizontal open segments in the square.

Comment: @RossMillikan A brief description of the idea is presented in M.Gardner, Knotted Doughnuts and Other Mathematical Entertainments, Chapter 12 (can be found on the net).

Comment: @A.Γ.:  Found it.  Thanks.  It doesn't look to me like it extends to the open square.

Comment: Are the line segments supposed to be of uniform length?

Comment: If you allow line segments of varying lengths, it should be possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Begin by covering the plane with exclusively horizontal and vertical closed line segments.  Start by covering the closed unit square:

- Horizontal line segments from $(0,y)$ to $(1,y)$ for $y\in[0,1]$.

Now, whenever you have the closed square $[0,A]^2$ covered, double the size of the covered region:

- Vertical line segments from $(x,0)$ to $(x,A)$ for $x\in (A,2A]$;
- Horizontal line segments from $(0,y)$ to $(2A,y)$ for $y \in (A,2A]$.

Repeat this to cover the plane.  Now you can cover the open square as well, simply by mapping $(x,y)\rightarrow \left(f(x), f(y)\right)$,
where $f$ nicely takes $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,1)$; for instance, $f(z)=1/(1+e^{-z})$ works.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yet I don't understand why you cover $\mathbf R^2$ before mapping : $(x, y) \rightarrow (f(x), f(y)$ ? What is the use of covering the plane first ?

Comment: The description of the covering of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is simpler.  The mapping is a bijection from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to the open square, and moreover it maps horizontal and vertical segments to segments; so the *images* of the segments used in covering the plane will cover the open square.

Comment: By the way, the covering as I've described it isn't exactly right, because it only extends up and to the right from the origin.  To fix it, alternate extending the covered square in the north/east directions and the south/west directions.